# Correlated subquery in HQL select clause

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql, correlated-subquery

I am using the following HQL:

> select new map(hdr.order_number as order_number, (select count(dtl)
>   from OrderDetail dtl where dtl.user_doc_id=hdr.user_doc_id AND
>   dtl.status <> 'Cancelled') as activeRowCount) from OrderHeader hdr
>   where hdr.user_doc_id  in ('PO1')

There is no association defined between OrderHeader and OrderDetail. When the above query is being executed, I am getting the following error:

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user_doc_id of: OrderHeader [select new map(hdr.order_number as order_number,(select count(dtl) from OrderDetail dtl where dtl.user_doc_id=hdr.user_doc_id AND dtl.status <> 'Cancelled') as activeRowCount) from OrderHeader hdr where hdr.user_doc_id  in ('PO00000
1')]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1451)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:312)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:487)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:611)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolveSelectExpression(DotNode.java:674)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolveSelectExpression(HqlSqlWalker.java:877)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2049)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.aliasedSelectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2229)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.constructor(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2419)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2116)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1981)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1513)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:584)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:914)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
        ... 88 more
```

I am not able to understand whre I am going wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: When I execute the corresponding SQL in DB, it is working fine:
SELECT hdr.order_number AS order_number,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM ao_po_detail dtl
  WHERE dtl.user_doc_id    =hdr.user_doc_id
  AND dtl.business_status <> 'Cancelled'
  ) AS activeRowCount
FROM ao_po_header hdr
WHERE hdr.user_doc_id IN ('PO000001')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using MAP as Hibernate entity mode. So the property names are case sensitive. My property name is USER_DOC_ID where as I am using user_doc_id and hence Hibernate complains:
"could not resolve property: user_doc_id of: OrderHeader"

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work. Just replace hdr1.id with whichever is the the primary key column of the table if not id

```
select new map(
hdr.order_number as order_number, 
(select count(dtl) from OrderHeader hdr1 join OrderDetail dtl on dtl.user_doc_id=hdr1.user_doc_id AND dtl.status <> 'Cancelled' AND hdr1.id = hdr.id) as activeRowCount)
from OrderHeader hdr where hdr.user_doc_id in ('PO1')
```

Comment: It is specified that there is no association between both entities. So would join work in HQL without any association defined between entities? Also is it not that in the suggested query an unnecessary additional join is being done?

Comment: @Avinash.. Join would not work without the associations being defined.

Comment: @Pratik..This is working even without the need of additional join suggested. We are using MAP entity mode for Hibernate and so the property names are case sensitive. The property name defined in the hbm file is USER_DOC_ID where as I am using user_doc_id. This is what is causing the issue.